# Get Data From JSONP Request In Asp.Net Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, jsonp

I am trying to `POST` data to an Asp.Net Web API on another one of my domains. I need to support IE9/8 so `CORS` won't cut it. When I make a call like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://www.myotherdomain.com/account",
data: "{firstName:'John', lastName:'Smith'}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "jsonp",
success: function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
},
error: function(x, e) {
    console.log(x);
}
});​
```

it makes a `GET` request to:

```
http://www.myotherdomain.com/account?
    callback=jQuery18008523724081460387_1347223856707&
    {firstName:'John',%20lastName:'Smith'}&
    _=1347223856725
```

I've implemented [this JSONP Formatter for ASP.NET Web API](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Apr/02/Creating-a-JSONP-Formatter-for-ASPNET-Web-API) and my server responds with a properly formatted JSONP response. I don't understand how to register a route to consume an account object.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Account",
    routeTemplate: "account",
    defaults: new { controller = "account", account = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

How do I deserialize an object from a querystring parameter without name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using JSON you could send the parameters as query string values. Let's suppose that you have the following model:

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and the following API controller:

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]User user)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { foo = "bar" });
    }
}
```

which could be consumed like that:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.myotherdomain.com/account?callback=?',
    data: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith' },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    },
    error: function (x, e) {
        console.log(x);
    }
});
```

Comment: ahh, how do I register a route for this in my WebApiConfig.cs?

Comment: You've already done that with the `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute` method.

Comment: thanks, from your example, I am hitting my `Get` function, but my `user` object has a null `FirstName` and `LastName`, any ideas?

Comment: I was missing the `{ get; set; }` after my properties, thank you for your help